# Algolia query with integer or numeric value returns no results

Tags: javascript, algolia

Hi I have a set of records that look something like this:

```
{
    id: 256,
    name: "Book",
    genre: "comedy",
    price: 25
}
```

if my query:

```
const client = algoliasearch(app_id,secret)
const index = client.initIndex('someindex')
index.search({
    query: 256,
    page: 0,
    hitsPerPage: 100,
}
```

is "Book" i get result, if my query is "comedy" I get results but if my query is 256 or 25 no results returned. Is there a parameter that I am misisng? Or how can I search for numerical value?

Comment: It is impossible to answer that question as long as we have no idea what the code that processes your request looks like.

Comment: Please post the code for _"my query"_.

Comment: Pretty standard query from their manual.